# Can's seems to use return pointer to double for printing value correctly with cout

Tags: c++, pointers, printf, cout

I can't print to screen the value pointed by a returned pointer to double with cout , if I use printf instead the value print correctly , if I use pointer to double which I declare inside the function with cout it also print correctly , if I debug I see the pointer to double returned correctly with it's value (pay attention that I point to static not local) , can't understand what's wrong here's the code (compile successfully in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double VAT=0.17;

double * addVAT(static double sum)
{
    sum = sum + (sum*VAT); 
    return &sum;
}


int main()
{
    double total = 120;
    double *totalWithVat;
    cout << "Type the total before VAT:";
    cin >> total;
    totalWithVat = addVAT(total);
    printf("The total with VAT is: %f \n", *totalWithVat);
    cout << *totalWithVat << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: I get from VC++ ["warning C4042: 'sum': has bad storage class"](https://godbolt.org/g/ds7Hb5) which should be an error, really. Your code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: what is this static in the declaration of addVAT. i don't think it compile

Comment: Does not compile, because `static double sum` is invalid storage class for a parameter.  The addVAT routine is returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: It is compile and run , the printf output is correct only the cout output gives strange output.

Comment: Dereferencing a dangling pointer is undefined behavior.  Undefined behavior can do the correct thing, and can give strange output.

Comment: "pay attention that I point to static not local" no you are not, this is not valid syntax

Comment: What's wrong with the code?   It is not valid C++, due to invalid use of `static` for a function argument.   Your compiler may accept it, but that just means your compiler does not diagnose errors as required by the standard.   Correct that problem (i.e. remove the misplaced `static`) and the code will compile, but then exhibit undefined behaviour, due to the same function returning a pointer to a variable of automatic storage duration that ceases to exist when the function returns (with subsequent code in the caller dereferencing that pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare function parameter as `static`, also you trying to return pointer on local variable, but when function leaves its scope its local variables don't exist anymore. You need to pass sum by reference if you want to get valid pointer on double:

```
double * addVAT(double& sum) // takes reference
{
    sum = sum + (sum*VAT); 
    return &sum;
}
```

But this double * addVAT(double& sum) function will change passed variable to it, in here total will be changed after calling method

```
int main()
{
    //...
    totalWithVat = addVAT(total);// in addVAT sum will referenced to total from main's scope, so it will return pointer to total

    std::cout << total; // will print the same as totalWithVat
    std::cout << totalWithVat; // will print the same as total, totalWithVat points to total
    //...
}
```

If you don't want to modify `total`, then just pass it by value and return double value like this:

```
double addVAT(double sum) 
{
    sum = sum + (sum*VAT); 
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I do not think OP wants to modify `total`

Comment: @Slava Yes, probably it's better to use function without modifying total. Just he used reference and pointers, so I thought he wants to know how  it's possible to make it with a help pointers. I will add this info in my answer to improve it. Thanks

Comment: I used static because as far as I know static make the otherwise local variable live long after the function is terminate it is suppose to save on heap instead of stack , am I wrong?

Comment: @Aviad430 Yes static variables have one instance and exist till the end of the program, but you can't use it as parameter. static variable initializes only once, so when you pass value to function you cannot initialize it later after, don't use static as parameter. By the way my gcc throws error on static parameter, don't you have an error there?

Comment: No the code compiled successfully in Visual Studio 2017 community edition.

Comment: @Aviad430 Well, don't use static as parameter, you can have undefined behavior!

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular function:

```
double totalWithVAT( double sum )
{
    const double vat = 1.17;
    return sum * vat; 
}

std::cout << "The total with VAT is:" << totalWithVAT( total ) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your `addVat` function.

```
double * addVAT(static double sum)
{
    sum = sum + (sum*VAT); 
    return &sum;
}
```

You need to remove the `static` from the parameter list. At least with GCC on Linux this causes a compilation error. When I do that I get

```
<source>: In function 'double* addVAT(double)':

<source>:8:24: warning: address of local variable 'sum' returned
 [-Wreturn-local-addr]

double * addVAT(double sum) 
                  ~~~~~~~^~~
Compiler returned: 0
```

Kinda what I expected.

In your `main` you have `total` which is passed **as a copy** to `addVat` where it has the name `sum`. So in memory (on the runtime stack) you have

main:total
main->addVat:sum

addVat modifies `sum` and returns a pointer to it. The problem is that upon return, `addVat` automatically releases the memory containing `sum`.

So now you have

main:total (unchanged)
main:totalWithVat -> memory where `sum` used to be

This is undefined behaviour. It might work, but also some other routine might re-use and modify the memory where `sum` used to be. This is probably what you are seeing. `printf` is lucky and gets the unmodified value of `sum` whilst `cout` gets a modified value.

As a solution to your problem, there are two possibilities. You could have just one input value that you modify, like this

```
void addVat(double& sum)
{
    sum += sum*VAT;
}

double total = 1.0;
addVat(total);
// total now ~1.17
```

Or you could have two values and not bother with pointers/references

```
double addVat(double sum)
{
    return sum + sum*VAT;
}

double total = 1.0;
double totalWithVat = addVat(total);
// totalWithVat now ~1.17
```

Comment: If a variable declared as static it suppose to save it's value on heap and not on stack , once the function is terminate the variable will stay on heap , without the static keyword the variable will be indeed a local variable and will terminate once the function done executing.

Comment: What you say is true, but a function parameter list is not one of the places where you can use `static`. It can be used at file scope, function scope and class scope. In these cases the memory isn't on the heap but rather another memory region (neither heap nor stack).

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to remove the static from the parameter and pass pointer instead of static , strange thing that the old code compiled and worked successfully with printf , this is the correct code which works in both cout and printf:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double VAT=0.17;

double * addVAT(double *sum)
{
    *sum = *sum + (*sum*VAT); 
    return sum;
}


int main()
{
    double varTotal = 0;
    double *total;
    total = &varTotal;
    double *totalWithVat;
    cout << "Type the total before VAT:";
    cin >> *total;
    totalWithVat = addVAT(total);
    printf("The total with VAT is: %f \n", *totalWithVat);
    cout << *totalWithVat << endl;
}
```

As long as I don't put static in parameter list it is working fine so I could write the code like this also:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double VAT = 0.17;

double * addVAT(double sum)
{
    static double sumstatic = sum;
    sumstatic = sumstatic + (sumstatic*VAT);
    return &sumstatic;
}


int main()
{
    double varTotal = 0;
    double total;
    double *totalWithVat;
    cout << "Type the total before VAT:";
    cin >> total;
    totalWithVat = addVAT(total);
    printf("The total with VAT is: %f \n", *totalWithVat);
    cout << "The total with VAT is: " << *totalWithVat << endl;
}
```